# How to get the entries of an HTML table with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am working on a Web Programming project and I need some help with one of the parts related to Internet cookies. The webpage has a table listing all webpage members and I would like to get access to the email of each one of them. However, I have tried many ways to do it, and I think that the table can't be found (when I print the variable containing it, it prints null). Then, I would appreciate it if someone could propose a good way to access a HTML table and get some of its entries. I leave here how the HTML table code and the JavaScript function to get the data from it.

**Table code:**

```
<table id="student-info">
    <tr>
        <th>Student</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img class="student-image" src="images/Student1.jpg" alt="Tarra Theisen profile picture"></td>
        <td>Tarra</td>
        <td>Theisen</td>
        <td>tarratheisen@gmail.com</td>
        <td><button class = "send-button"><i class="far fa-paper-plane"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img class="student-image" src="images/Student2.jpeg" alt="Patrick Beverley profile picture"></td>
        <td>Patrick</td>
        <td>Beverley</td>
        <td>patrickbev@gmail.com</td>
        <td><button class = "send-button"><i class="far fa-paper-plane"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Function code in JS:**

```
function showTableData() {
     
     var myTab = document.getElementById('student-info');

        // LOOP THROUGH EACH ROW OF THE TABLE AFTER HEADER.
        for (i = 1; i < myTab.rows.length; i++) {

            // GET THE CELLS COLLECTION OF THE CURRENT ROW.
            var objCells = myTab.rows.item(i).cells;

            // LOOP THROUGH EACH CELL OF THE CURENT ROW TO READ CELL VALUES.
            for (var j = 0; j < objCells.length; j++) {
              alert(objCells.item(j).innerHTML);
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better approach would be to give email fields class and then fetch those fields.

```js
(function showTableData() {
  var email = [];
  var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("email");
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    email.push(arr[i].innerHTML);
  }
  console.log(email);
})();
```

```html
<table id="student-info">
      <tr>
        <th>Student</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img class="student-image" alt="Tarra Theisen profile picture" />
        </td>
        <td>Tarra</td>
        <td>Theisen</td>
        <td class="email">tarratheisen@gmail.com</td>
        <td>
          <button class="send-button">
            <i class="far fa-paper-plane"></i>
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img class="student-image" alt="Patrick Beverley profile picture" />
        </td>
        <td>Patrick</td>
        <td>Beverley</td>
        <td class="email">patrickbev@gmail.com</td>
        <td>
          <button class="send-button">
            <i class="far fa-paper-plane"></i>
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working fine for me. If you want to get just the email you know it's index is 3 so just grab it that way

```js
function showTableData() { 
  var myTab = document.getElementById('student-info');
  var emailList = document.getElementById('emails');
  for (i = 1; i < myTab.rows.length; i++) {
    var objCells = myTab.rows.item(i).cells;
    for (var j = 0; j < objCells.length; j++) {
      if (j === 3) {
        var emailText = objCells.item(j).innerHTML;
        var email = document.createElement('li');
        email.appendChild(document.createTextNode(emailText));
        emailList.appendChild(email);
      }
    }
  }
}

showTableData();
```

```html
<table id="student-info">
    <tr>
        <th>Student</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img class="student-image" src="images/Student1.jpg" alt="Tarra Theisen profile picture"></td>
        <td>Tarra</td>
        <td>Theisen</td>
        <td>tarratheisen@gmail.com</td>
        <td><button class = "send-button"><i class="far fa-paper-plane"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img class="student-image" src="images/Student2.jpeg" alt="Patrick Beverley profile picture"></td>
        <td>Patrick</td>
        <td>Beverley</td>
        <td>patrickbev@gmail.com</td>
        <td><button class = "send-button"><i class="far fa-paper-plane"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<ul id="emails">
Emails
</ul>
```